# Java 8 - map to comma separated pairs in brackets

Tags: java-8

What is the best way in **Java 8** to get from

```
Map<Integer, Integer>
```

to a String like:

```
[k1,v1],[k2,v2],[k3,v3]...
```

I am looking at something like this, but I don't know how to "return" or "map" the `StringBuilder`:

```
map.forEach( (k,v) -> s.append("[").append(k).append(",").append(v).append("]") )
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

In any case, I believe `StringBuilder` is not suitable for multithreading in case of future paralelism.

Note that I could iterate over the Map and create all the structure in an old fashion, but I would like to see how it could be done with some new Java8 features.

I think some `toString()` by chance already returns the map values in brackets, which could be convenient, although it is not really a good idea to rely on this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
map.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .map(e -> "[" + e.getKey() + "," + e.getValue() + "]")
   .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: The entrySet!  Thanks. By the way, I cannot edit but there is a `);` missing at the end